# Compile-Time Conditional Type Operation with Macros

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to create a macro that simplifies to something depending on the type of the parameter.

To keep things simple, we'll say the types are c-style strings. Here is the situation:

```
int FunctionA( const char* input );
int FunctionB( const wchar_t* input );

#define Function( input ) \
    input is of type char \
        FunctionA( input ) \
    input is of type wchar_t \
        FunctionB( input )
// is there something else I can do to simplify this operation at compile time?
// maybe somehow use decltype( input ) to narrow which function to use?
// maybe if constexpr ( input ) or something? is there a constexpr version of the ?: operator?
// maybe std::is_same?
```

The primary issue is that this has to substitute to something that can be passed as a parameter. Semicolons won't work.

e.g.

```
Foo( Function( "Example" ) );
```

What are my options using C++17?

Comment: what about using template rather than preprocessor macro ?

Comment: How could you use a template to resolve a function without wrapping the function in another function @bruno?

Comment: `without wrapping the function in another function` - why is that a problem?

Comment: @KamilCuk the function is a marker for something to happen after the product is built. Similar to how VMProtect does their string encryption using the function as a marker for the string.

Comment: `after the product is built` - hm.... if you mark the template function as inline (and use proper compiler that actually inlines), the function name shouldn't even show up in the final executable. Does that help? If that is a C interface, I think you can use `_Generic` like C11, but I don't think that's C++17. You can also go with a macro with `if constexpr (typeid(input) == typeid(char)) functionA(input) else if .... ` the compiler should optimize the unreachable branches.

Comment: what about simply call `FunctionA()` and `FunctionB()` with the same name so the you demand the resolution to the compiler (resolution of the overloading)?

Comment: The functions `FunctionA` and `FunctionB` are not part of my department and I cannot change them. @max66

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't think typeid is evaluated at compile time. Anyway, the issue is that the constexpr requires a semicolon at the end of the line or else it doesnt compile

Comment: so what about make `Function()`, instead of a macro, two overloaded functions; the first one receiving a `const char *` and calling `FunctionA()`, the second one receiving a `const wchar_t *` and calling `FunctionB()` ?

Comment: Are you using gcc? Maybe `__extension({ })` with `if constexpr` and [`ctti::type_id`](https://github.com/Manu343726/ctti) ...

Answer (score 1):

First approach:

Ternary operators with typeid comparisons. The `&input[0]` is an old C trick used to decay the type of an array of X elements into a pointer to type (we could also use `input + 0`). The `reinterpret_cast` is used to silence warnings/errors when converting the pointer.

```
#define Function(input)  \
    ( \
        typeid(&input[0]) == typeid(const char*) || \
        typeid(&input[0]) == typeid(char*) \
    ) ? ( \
        FunctionA(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(input)) \
    ) : ( \
        typeid(&input[0]) == typeid(const wchar_t*) || \
        typeid(&input[0]) == typeid(wchar_t*) \
    ) ? ( \
        FunctionB(reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t*>(input)) \
    ) : ( \
        assert(0), \
        0 \
    )

void main1() {
    Foo(Function("Example"));
}
```

Second approach:

A template with specialized instantiation:

```
template<typename T> inline int 
Function2(T t);
template<> inline int 
Function2<const char*>(const char* t) {
    return FunctionA(t);
}
template<> inline int 
Function2<const wchar_t*>(const wchar_t* t) {
    return FunctionB(t);
}

void main2() {
    Foo(Function2("Example"));
}
```

Both codes compile into:

```
        push    rax
        mov     edi, offset .L.str
        call    FunctionA(char const*)
        mov     edi, eax
        pop     rax
        jmp     Foo(int)
```

using clang with `-O2` as shown on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/-XDoQf). But I guess the first one is safer for your case.

Comment: I had no idea that the ternary operator could be used to evaluate compile-time code. :o

Comment: Really it isn't. A good enough compiler with good enough optimization will inline the statements. And all similar statements. I observed it didn't work with `-O1`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ has overloading so maybe you could simply do:

```
inline int Function( const char* input ){ return FunctionA(input); }
inline int Function( const wchar_t* input ){ return FunctionB(input); }
```

instead of the macro.